# docker runでコンテナを起動しようとしたらnpm ERR！が出る

Tags: docker

[Vue.jsの開発環境をDockerで構築する手順 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/kskinaba/items/44077529ff2abcd1fcd4)

上記の記事を参考にdockerを用いてVueの環境構築をしています。

```
docker build --tag zatu:latest --file Dockerfile .
```

でイメージを作成し、

```
docker run --rm -it --name zatu1 -p 8080:8080 -v ${PWD}:/zatubako -v /zatubako/node_modules zatu:latest
```

でコンテナを起動しようとしましたが、以下のエラーが出ました。

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /zatubako/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/zatubako/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-21T08_57_53_482Z-debug.log
```

どうかご享受お願いします。

Dokcerfile

```
FROM node:10.17.0-alpine3.9
WORKDIR /zatubako
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

ディレクトリ構成

```
.
├── zatubako
│   ├── babel.config.js
│   ├── dist 
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
├── README.md
└── dockerfile
├── .dockerignore
└── docker-compose.yml
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "zatubako",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  },
  {
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service serve"
  }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

マウントしているディレクトリが間違っていそうです。

おそらくDockerfileのある場所で`docker run`を実行しているでしょうから、そこからみてpackage.jsonの位置は`zatubako/package.json`に存在します。

つまり、実行コマンドは次のようになると考えられます。

```sh
docker run --rm -it --name zatu1 -p 8080:8080 -v ${PWD}/zatubako:/zatubako -v /zatubako/node_modules zatu:latest
```

### 追記

package.jsonがJSONのsyntax errorを起こしています。正しくは以下の通りです。

```js
{
  "name": "zatubako",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service serve"
  }
}
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。再度イメージをビルドし上記のコマンドを実行したところ、また上記のようなエラーが出てしまいました。ただ今回はnpm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json・・・のようなエラーでしたので、おそらくpackage.jsonがおかしいのかなとおもいました

Comment: package.jsonの情報の追記をお願いします。

Comment: package.jsonを追加しました。またnpm install --save @vue/cli-serviceで vue-cli-serviceをインストールしていますがそれがうまく機能していないようです。

Comment: 回答に追記しました。たとえばJSONの有効性を https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ なものでチェックするのもありです。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。上記のpackage.jsonにかえてdocker runをおこなったのですがnpm ERR! zatubako@1.0.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the zatubako@1.0.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

Comment: vue-cli-serviceが無いというエラーでしょう。`@vue/cli-service` をinstallしておきましょう。installが完了したらpackage.jsonが変更されるはずです。
これに関しては参考にしている記事にも同様の対処方法が書いてあるかとおもいます。
https://qiita.com/kskinaba/items/44077529ff2abcd1fcd4#%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%91