# docker compose時にThis relative module was not found:と出る。

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js

`docker compose up` コマンドを実行した際以下のようなエラーが出てしまい、localhost:8080にアクセスできません。
どうやらsrcファイルのmain.jsが見つからないようなのですがディレクトリを見たら普通にあるので困っています。どうかご享受お願いします。

```
<s> [webpack.Progress] 98% after emitting
web    |  ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors2:33:24 AM
web    |
web    | This relative module was not found:
web    |
web    | * ./src/main.js in multi ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js, multi ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js ./src/main.js
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10.17.0-alpine3.9
WORKDIR /zatubako
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/zatubako'
      - '/zatubako/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

**ディレクトリ構造**

```
zatubako
├─docker-compose.yml
├─node_modules
├─src
│ ├─App.vue
│ ├─main.js
│ └─assets
│      │
│      └─logo
├─.babelrc             
├─index.html
├─webpack.config
├─.dockerignore
└─package.json
└─Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1):

- [docker runでコンテナを起動しようとしたらnpm ERR！が出る - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/66909/2808)

の続きでよいでしょうか。

発生しているのは、同じく参照されているページの[エラー（その３）](https://qiita.com/kskinaba/items/44077529ff2abcd1fcd4#%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%9D%E3%81%AE%EF%BC%93)の内容です。
webpackを最新化してみてください。

```
npm add webpack@latest
```

`package.json`結果:

```
-    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
+    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。webpackの最新化を試してみましたが結果は変わりませんでした。docker-compose psで確認するとStateはUpになっており、Portも表示されていますが指定されたパスはありませんと出ます。

Comment: [こちらが今回再現したコードです](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so66942)。私の環境では、webpackのアップデート前(`c257cc7c3`)に`npm run serve`した場合に質問のエラーが出力され、アップデート後では正常起動しています。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。上記のコードをnpm　run serveしたら動きました。